# Units of a group ring.

Tags: ring-theory, group-rings

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rationals and $G$ a group. Then we consider the group ring $\mathbb{Q}[G]$.

Since the operation on $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ restricted to $G$ is just the group operation, I know that $G$ is a subgroup of the units of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$.

How can we describe all units of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$?

Comment: This could be interesting: http://www.mathstat.ualberta.ca/people/Faculty/Sehgal/publications/057.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general group $G$ this is a hard problem.

Let me mention the partial progress that I remember.

For one thing, if $G$ isn't torsion-free, there is a theorem in Passman's *Algebraic structure of group rings* that says that the units of $F[G]$ for a field $F$ are trivial iff $G$ is $F_2[C_2]$, $F_2[C_3]$ or $F_3[C_2]$. ($F_i$ denotes a field of order $i$ and $C_i$ the cyclic group order $i$.)

So attention is usually restricted to torsion-free groups, and the open conjecture is the **unit conjecture** that asks if $F[G]$ has trivial units for any field $F$ and any torsion-free group $G$.

Two good resources I can recommend are Passman's *Algebraic structure of group rings* and Lam's *First course on noncommutative rings* I think has some information on this. I don't have copies of Milies' group ring books, but I remember when I consulted them they were very good too.

Finally, through [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/79702/19965) I found a very interesting [slide set](https://web.archive.org/web/20131102054744/http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/craven/docs/seminars/220909slides.pdf) for a talk about the difficulty of the conjecture, which looks very good.

Comment: The link to the slides is broken. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @Breakfastisready I managed to find a link in the Wayback Machine that seems to work. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer but some  inspiration. 
In this general setting you've given nothing is known about the group of units of this ring, except for - as you already mentioned - it has a subgroup isomorphic to $G$.

In special cases there are some references I can give you:

Read the [Wikipedia article about group rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) in general. If $G$ is a finite group, modules over the group ring coincide with linear representations of $G$ and as $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ is a module over itself, it contains every linear representation of $G$. This is called the **regular representation**.

Furthermore there is an old [article of Higman](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/higman.pdf) having some nice results in the case of $G$ finite abelian.

Last but not least I'd like [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142899/units-in-a-group-algebra) in MO which collects some cases over group algebras.

Hope that helps you. Maybe someone else knows something more about units.

Enjoy, Tom